# Set session on first page load with no authorisation. AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, session

How to set a session in AngularJs before user authentication. For example, I am using the bellow code to run a function, after user authentication is successful:

```
function setSessionLocale(locale) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('locale', locale);
  //...
}

$rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, setSessionLocale);
```

But I would like to use something like:

```
function setSessionBefore(locale) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('locale', locale);
  //...
}

$rootScope.$on('THE_RIGHT_EVENTS', setSessionBefore);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is appending to `app.run` a function, where `app.run` is angular module.

here how it looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['MyJsMethods_if_there_is_any']);

app.run(function (locale) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('locale', locale);
  }
});
```